# Laravel unit test - mock PDF?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing

I'm trying to do unit test on my export class where I use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as PDF. I'm trying to use mock so I can fake it to throw exception so I can test the code part for handling exception but I got this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Mockery_0_Barryvdh_DomPDF_Facade_Pdf::shouldReceive() in \vendor\mockery\mockery\library\Mockery\Loader\EvalLoader.php(24) : eval()'d code on line 997

I'm thinking maybe I didn't do it right with the mock? Or maybe there's another way I can test the exception part?

```
use Mockery;
Mockery::mock(\Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\Pdf::class)->shouldReceive('loadHTML')->andThrow(new \Exception('Mocked PDF Load Error'));
```

Here's the export class:

```
namespace App\Exports;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\Pdf;

class DataPdfExport
{
    protected $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function export()
    {
        try {
            $randomSuffix = Str::random(8);

            if (empty($html)) {
                $html = view('exports.data-pdf', ['data' => $this->data])->render();
            }

            $pdf = PDF::loadHTML($html);
            $file = 'data'. now()->format('Ymd') . '-' . $randomSuffix. '.pdf';

            return ['error' => false, 'pdf' => $pdf, 'file' => $file];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error('ExcelExport Error: '.$e->getMessage());
            return ['error' => true, 'message' => 'Failed pdf export. Please try again later.'];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used [`barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf), but I did check the [Facade](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/blob/master/src/Facade/Pdf.php) and it is a normal Facade.

The way of [mocking a Facade](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/mocking#mocking-facades) is by simply calling the mocking method, in your case:

```php
\Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\Pdf::shouldReceive('loadHTML')
    ->andThrow(new \Exception('Mocked PDF Load Error'));
```

That should do the trick!